# Backbone model on change not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've pasted my code below and 'on change' is not firing when a data is pushed into already existing array within the model, but when whole array is reset it gets fired.

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    "subject" : [0,4]   
  },

  initialize : function() {
    this.on('change',this.fetchResults);
  },

  fetchResults : function() {
    console.log("fetch");
  }

});

var myModel = new BookModel();
var subjects = myModel.get('subject');
subjects.push(2);  //fetch does not get called 
//subjects = [];   //fetch gets called 
myModel.set({"subject": subjects});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WnNQk/

Comment: i've made changes to above code .. var subjects = myModel.get('subject').slice();
subjects.push(2); this seem to work, is this correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backbone triggers a *change* event when the value actually changes. `myModel.get('subject')`yields a reference to an array. You then modify and set it with `myModel.set({"subject": subjects})`, but it is the same reference : the value has not changed, the event is not triggered.

[Cloning](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) or [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array will give you the behavior you expect :

```
var subjects = _.clone(myModel.get('subject'));
subjects.push(2);
myModel.set({"subject": subjects});
```

or

```
var subjects = myModel.get('subject').slice();
subjects.push(2);
myModel.set({"subject": subjects});
```

On a related note, using an array in the defaults will lead to a shared array between instances. In this case, I would advise to use a function to build your defaults :

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            "subject": [0, 4]   
        }
    }
});
```